# Textbox hide behind animation of gif

Tags: c++, winapi, gif, animated-gif

I'm make window in c++ with supporting winapi(not MFC), and I made gif animation on window with gdi++, and I create TextBox, it  showing, but some part is behind gif. Image in this link : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4mIS.jpg)

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {


    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE: 




            hMWDC = GetDC(hwnd);
            pGphcs = new Graphics(hMWDC);
            WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
            GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);
            PathRemoveFileSpecW(path);
            PathAppendW(path, L"gifs\\test.gif");
            pImg = new Image(path);
            if (pImg) {
                nFrmCnt = pImg->GetFrameCount(&FrameDimensionTime);
                SetTimer(hwnd, DRAW_ANIM, 100, NULL);

            }

        break;


    case WM_TIMER:
        if (wParam == DRAW_ANIM)
        {
            pImg->SelectActiveFrame(&FrameDimensionTime, nFrm);
            Rect DRC(0, 0, pImg->GetWidth(), pImg->GetHeight());
            pGphcs->Clear(Color(128, 128, 128));
            pGphcs->DrawImage(pImg, DRC);
            if (nFrm < (nFrmCnt - 1)) nFrm++; else nFrm = 0;
        }
        break;


hwndText = CreateWindow(L"EDIT",
        L"",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        350, 480, 55, 20,
        hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I expected gif as background and TextBox will be front of it.
But nothing, :(

Comment: Adding `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` when creating main window could help.

Comment: To main hwnd, yes?

Comment: Yes, to main window. It cuts areas occupied by children form parent window HDC's painting area.

Comment: Please, can you write it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons by default device context for given `HWND` does not clip a child window from the parent window's client area.

If parent window draws something in the same location as the child window, it draws also over child window. Accepting some (nowadays minimal) performance hit you can automatically clip children windows form main frame window painting area, by adding `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style when **creating main frame window**. With this style any `HDC` obtained for main frame window will have area occupied by child control excluded form painting area. This protects child window from overpainting by it's parent window activity.

Setting `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` for **main frame window** should solve your problem.

```
hwnd = CreateWindow( class_name, title, some_styles | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, ... );
```

Sometimes child windows overlap each other and then they can overdraw each other. In this case `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` applied to **child windows** (of the same parent window), protects one child form another painting.